# How apply CSS to a iOS NSAttributedString

Tags: html, ios, css, objective-c

I'm working in a iOS project and I've got this HTML text that i need to display in a UITextView:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="Link: http://google.com">http://google.com/</a><br><span class="wysiwyg-color-d24b57 ">TEST<br><i><span class="wysiwyg-color-704938 ">TEST2<br></span></i></span><div class="wysiwyg-text-align-left "><span class="wysiwyg-color-d24b57 "><span class="wysiwyg-color-704938 "><u><span class="wysiwyg-color-3a529c ">Test3<br>TEST4<br><br></span></u><span class="wysiwyg-color-3a529c wysiwyg-font-size-x-large ">Test5</span><u><span class="wysiwyg-color-3a529c "><br><br><br></span></u></span></span></div>
```

So far, I've created the NSAttributedString and the UITextView:

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                            initWithData: [example.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                            options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
                                            documentAttributes: nil
                                            error: nil
                                            ];


UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
textView.frame = [node labelFrame];
textView.attributedText = attributedString;
textView.editable = NO;
textView.selectable = YES;
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

return textView;
```

Now I have to apply the wysiwyg CSS on it, as at the moment, color, font-size and alignment are not working.

Does anybody have any idea how to to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can like this way

```
let divHtml = "<div style=\"font-family:Helvetica;font-size:14px;line-height:22px\" >" + YOUR TEXT + "</div>"
        let attributedString = try! NSAttributedString(data: divHtml.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)

textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: I've got different fonts, sizes and colors for different parts of the HTML text, what I need is to be able to identify tags like this inside the text: **span class="wysiwyg-color-d24b57"**

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya how to add external css